# Brainfreeze! reduce a number by a percentage so that the number after X iterations is below 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, percentages, permutation-cycles

I am having a sort of brainfreeze or cannot express the mathematical formula for the following:

I have a Natural Number X and I want to reduce it by a Percentage e.g 4% Y times that after Y iterations I get a X < 1.
What is the mathematical formula for it and how to calulcate the iterations?

Y1=X*0,96

Y2=Y1*0,94 etc.etc.

Something like
f(x) = x*09
f(x) = y < 1

The idea behind it is to calculate an investment sum which by receiving a yearly dividen should be close to zero , meaning the initial investment has already been returned.

Comment: Why does Y2 = Y1 * 0,94?